# Getting error while namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query..), when using in-clause in query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, in-clause, batch-updates

I am trying to update a table in batch using org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. 
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query...) method;
    My query contains in-clause, because of which I am getting SQL error like this:

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][1091][10824][4.14.113] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance [1271, 1272] is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815.
```

Below is my data which I want to batch update. It is Map of contractId(String) as key and value as List of taskids(Integer)
    Data:

```
{10008=[1271, 1272], 10007=[1269, 1270], 10009=[1273, 1274], 10011=[1277, 1278], 10010=[1275, 1276], 10012=[1279], 10006=[1267, 1268]}

where key is the CONTRACT_ID (String) and value is list of TASK_ID ( Integer)
e.g. CONTRACT_ID are 10008, 10007, 10009 etc.
and respective TASK_ID are [1271, 1272], [1269, 1270], [1273, 1274] etc.
```

I tried calling namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update inside the loop, and it is working fine, I am able to update the same query using the single update

### single update

```
@Override
public int assignUserTask(String customerId, String userId, Map<String, List<Integer>> resultMap)
        throws ApplicationException {

    int totalCount = 0;
    String ts = DateUtils.getCurrentDatetimeStamp();
    String todaysDate = DateUtils.getTodaysDate();

    String query = CommonUtils.buildQuery("UPDATE EM_WF_USER_QUEUE SET", "CURRENT_USER_ID = :currentUserId,",
            "INITIAL_USER_ID = :initialUserId,", "USER_REASSIGN_TYPE_CD = 'GW',",
            "USER_REASSIGN_TIME = :userReassignTime,", "LAST_CENTRAL_QUEUE_DATE = :lastCentralQueueData,",
            "REASSIGN_CENTRAL_DATE = :reassignCentralDate,", "ORG_GW_CRT_TIME = :orgGwCreateTime,",
            "LAST_UPDT_USER = :lastUpdtUser ,", "LAST_UPDT_TIME = :lastUpdtTime",
            "WHERE CONTRACT_ID = :contractId AND TASK_ID IN (:taskIds)",
            "AND CUSTOMER_ID = :customerId AND CURRENT_USER_ID = 'UNASSIGNED'",
            "AND OVERIDE_IND = 'N' AND QUEUE_STATUS != 'CLOSED'");

    try {

        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("currentUserId", userId);
        params.addValue("initialUserId", userId);
        params.addValue("userReassignTime", ts);
        params.addValue("lastCentralQueueData", todaysDate);
        params.addValue("reassignCentralDate", todaysDate);
        params.addValue("orgGwCreateTime", ts);
        params.addValue("lastUpdtUser", userId);
        params.addValue("lastUpdtTime", ts);
        params.addValue("customerId", customerId);

        for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
            params.addValue("contractId", entry.getKey());
            params.addValue("taskIds", entry.getValue());

            totalCount += namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, params);
        }
        return totalCount;

    } catch (DataAccessException exp) {
        throw new CustomException(exp, "Exception occured!");
    }
}
```

### batch update

@Override
    public int assignUserTask(String customerId, String userId, Map> resultMap)
            throws CustomException {

```
    String ts = DateUtils.getCurrentDatetimeStamp();
    String todaysDate = DateUtils.getTodaysDate();

    String query = CommonUtils.buildQuery("UPDATE EM_WF_USER_TASK SET", "CURRENT_USER_ID = :currentUserId,",
            "INITIAL_USER_ID = :initialUserId,", "USER_REASSIGN_TIME = :userReassignTime,",
            "LAST_CENTRAL_QUEUE_DATE = :lastCentralQueueData,", "REASSIGN_CENTRAL_DATE = :reassignCentralDate,",
            "ORG_GW_CRT_TIME = :orgGwCreateTime,", "LAST_UPDT_USER = :lastUpdtUser ,",
            "LAST_UPDT_TIME = :lastUpdtTime", "WHERE CONTRACT_ID = :contractId AND TASK_ID IN (:taskIds)",
            "AND CUSTOMER_ID = :customerId AND CURRENT_USER_ID = 'UNASSIGNED'",
            "AND ACTIVE_IND = 'Y' AND TASK_STATUS != 'CLOSED'");

    try {

        List<MapSqlParameterSource> batchArgs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
            MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            params.addValue("currentUserId", userId);
            params.addValue("initialUserId", userId);
            params.addValue("userReassignTime", ts);
            params.addValue("lastCentralQueueData", todaysDate);
            params.addValue("reassignCentralDate", todaysDate);
            params.addValue("orgGwCreateTime", ts);
            params.addValue("lastUpdtUser", userId);
            params.addValue("lastUpdtTime", ts);
            params.addValue("contractId", entry.getKey());
            params.addValue("taskIds", entry.getValue());
            params.addValue("customerId", customerId);

            batchArgs.add(params);
        }

        int[] retVal = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query,
                batchArgs.toArray(new MapSqlParameterSource[resultMap.size()]));

        return retVal.length;

    } catch (DataAccessException exp) {
        throw new CustomException(exp, "Exception occured!");
    }
}
```

I am expecting the queries to run in a batch when I am using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query..)`
 but it is giving type conversion error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE EM_WF_USER_TASK SET
>   CURRENT_USER_ID = ?, INITIAL_USER_ID = ?, USER_REASSIGN_TYPE_CD =
>   'GW', USER_REASSIGN_TIME = ?, LAST_CENTRAL_QUEUE_DATE = ?,
>   REASSIGN_CENTRAL_DATE = ?, ORG_GW_CRT_TIME = ?, LAST_UPDT_USER = ? ,
>   LAST_UPDT_TIME = ? WHERE CONTRACT_ID = ? AND TASK_ID IN (?, ?) AND
>   CUSTOMER_ID = ? AND CURRENT_USER_ID = 'UNASSIGNED' AND ACTIVE_IND =
>   'Y' AND TASK_STATUS != 'CLOSED' ]; nested exception is
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException:
>   [jcc][1091][10824][4.14.113] Invalid data conversion: Parameter
>   instance [1271, 1272] is invalid for the requested conversion.
>   ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:634)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:924)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:43)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:357)
>         at com.medicare.mss.daoImpl.ContractDAO.assignUserTask(ContractDAO.java:274)
>         ... 164 more
>       Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][1091][10824][4.14.113] Invalid data conversion: Parameter
>   instance [1271, 1272] is invalid for the requested conversion.
>   ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
>         at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:677)
>         at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
>         at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:103)
>         at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.c(po.java:2630)
>         at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.setObject(po.java:2409)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:411)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:232)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:163)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.setStatementParameters(BatchUpdateUtils.java:70)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.access$000(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:33)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils$1.setValues(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:50)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$2(JdbcTemplate.java:932)
>         at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
>         ... 169 more
>       com.medicare.mss.exception.ApplicationException: Error occured while assignUserTask!
>         at com.medicare.mss.daoImpl.ContractDAO.assignUserTask(ContractDAO.java:279)
>         at com.medicare.mss.daoImpl.ContractDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$30e66146.invoke()
>         ...
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the issue is with IN clause in the batchUpdate query. Please check the below link. Hope this helps:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21935

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am able fix this issue by upgrading my spring boot version to 2.2.0. Basically, it was not supported in the older version (older then 5.1.3.RELEASE) of spring-jdbc. This issue got fixed as part of 5.1.3.RELEASE. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v5.1.3.RELEASE

Comment: Good to hear! :) Thank you too!